# Button ordering in the reopen review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, user-interface, reopen-closed

The review queues buttons tend to rank from “positive feedback” to “negative feedback” to mostly constant edit and skip.  The question reopening queue stands out a bit: first “close”, then edit, then “open”.

<my life>

I'm usually in the flow enough for this not to be a problem.  But every now and then, a real interesting question comes up.  So I'll read it more thoroughly (read: in an “answering” mindset rather than an “is this supposed to be here?” one).  And if it's just beneath the threshold of answering, I'll just shrug, wonder why the heck it was up for review in the first place, and move on by muscle-memory-clicking on “Looks OK”.

Oops.

As of now I've had one frantic session of searching for an “undo” button (I'm very sorry, asker; I was the first to review, you're probably good by now anyway), and one failed audit (oh well).

</my life>

But infrequent as it is, it's bound to happen again.

I couldn't find a former discussion on the review queues' UI design. So I'm not sure if the *status quo* is “most frequent action first” or historical *ad-hoc*. Or something else?

I'm not even sure I'd like it any different.  I just know I've been confused by it already, and may not be the only one.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: That does seems a bit inconsistent from a UX perspective.

Comment: Big Meta dupe: [Inconsistency of button positions in review queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238797/266187)

Comment: At first I was like "How could I have missed it despite searching for it, it's got like all the keywords". Then I noticed the different favicon. I'm so very not used to meta.SO and meta.SE being separate. Thanks for the link!